# What is the correct and culture independent way to handle Key in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, keyboard

I'm quite confused about handling of Key http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.key.aspx in a KeyEventArgs.
For example: I want to handle colon key (made on my Italian keyboard with dot + Shift), so I write some code like this

```
if ( e.Key == Key.OemPeriod && e.KeyboardDevice.Modifiers == ModifierKeys.Shift) {
    // Code 
}
```

But this approach isn't correct because work only with Italian keyboard. What is the correct and culture independent way to handle Key in WPF?

Comment: Good question, actually. There's no equivalent of `KeyPress` in WPF, so I suspect the solution won't be so straightforward. Also, if you could provide a bit more context to your question, we might be able to suggest something more easily.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried handling the [PreviewTextInput](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.previewtextinput.aspx) or [TextInput](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.textinput.aspx) events instead? These events should give you the text entered (which is device-independent) as opposed to the physical key pressed (which is device-dependent).

Comment: PreviewTextInput and TextInput provides the correct info. When I have made my test the TextInput event is trapped elsewhere and don't reach my control, but PreviewTextInput works fine.
Thanks

Comment: My question is not only how to get char from a TextBox. Is more generally a question about the correct way to made this conversion from Keyboard event to char representation. 
Because I found very strange a kind of culture depended limit in the Keyboard handling infrastracture.

Comment: Those events are just the WPF wrapper around the underlying Windows messages. You get the same sequence of events in WinForms, VB, MFC, WinAPI, etc, only the event/message names differ. Windows has always worked like that AFAIK.